# Jquery .on() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0u7yv2o/)

Please have a look at the above fiddle. The *.on* method seems to be not working.
I'm sure I must be missing something obvious.?

**JS**

```
var rand;
$('button').click(function(){
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $('#maindiv').append('<div style="cursor:pointer" id="dyn_user_'+rand+'">'+rand+'</div>');

});

$("[id^='dyn_user_']").on('click',function(event){  
    console.log('On method!');
    $('#maindiv').append('<div style="cursor:pointer" id="dyn_user_"'+rand+'">'+rand+'</div>');
});
```

My main objective was to try to see in .on() is working if I generate the same element (in this case 'div' with id="dyn_user_somerandnumber") inside .on() . But I got stuck with .on() method not working. 
I'm sorry if it sounds confusing.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `$("[id^='dyn_user_']")`?

Comment: Are you trying with .click() method ? To know if your selector works ? Or maybe add $("[id^='dyn_user_']").css('background','red') before to test

Comment: I'll add additional comment to the question. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically added elements. So you should bind to an existing element using the syntax:

```
$('#maindiv').on('click',"[id^='dyn_user_']",function(event){  
    console.log('On method!');
    $('#maindiv').append('<div style="cursor:pointer" id="dyn_user_"'+rand+'">'+rand+'</div>');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v0u7yv2o/1/)**

Comment: Awesome! Should have thought of this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

At the time you bind the click event `[id^='dyn_user_']` does not exist, so there is nothing bound.  You would have to bind the event to an existing element, then use the filter to only have it occur for the elements you want.  Like this:

```js
$(document).on('click',"[id^='dyn_user_']", function(event){  
    console.log('On method!');
    $('#maindiv').append('<div style="cursor:pointer" id="dyn_user_"'+rand+'">'+rand+'</div>');
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0u7yv2o/2/

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering is should I bind to `document` or `div` it self.

Comment: Either one will work - binding it to `div` acts as an additional filter for the click event, and might perform a bit better as it won't even bother trying to see if it needs to fire the event for elements that are not `div`